# Perpendicular symbol with litle square

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I insert this symbol in math environment? \Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, I have only set it up for `\displaystyle`.  If you need smaller math styles, let me know.

One can change the square size with `\sqdim`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\sqdim{.4ex}
\newcommand\perpsq{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{\perp}
  {\kern\sqdim\rule[\sqdim]{\sqdim}{.4pt}\rule[.4pt]{.4pt}{\sqdim}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \perpsq B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here with `\sqdim` set to `.3ex`:

[image]